# How to make a Telegram bot just available for the owner

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I have a **telegram bot** and now I like to make it available just for me.
I found a article which said that I can test my id but my code doesn't work :( ...
Here is my code :

```
import time
import random
import datetime
import telepot
from telepot.loop import MessageLoop

def handle(msg):

chat_id = msg['chat']['id']

command = msg['text']
number = 1111

print 'Got command: %s' % command


if command == '/roll' & command.from_id(11111):
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id, random.randint(1,6))

bot = telepot.Bot('Token')

MessageLoop(bot, handle).run_as_thread()
print 'I am listening ...'

while 1:
time.sleep(10)
```

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: if chat_id == 109780439:

Comment: Thanks for helping :D it works